# Java Translucent Selection Box

Tags: java

For custom rendering, I've created a class that extends JPanel and overrides the paintComponent method. In the custom paintComponent I rendering multiple shape objects held in a array. What I would like to add is the ability to drag and select 1 or more of the shapes. While dragging I would like to show a translucent rectangle defining the selection region akin to what is seen in Windows Explorer. Can any provide a starting point for accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All,

Thanks for the suggestions. Ended up resolving this by adapting some the code used in this rather clever demo. http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5299064&start=19

```
public class ExamplePanel extends JPanel
{
    Rectangle2D.Double selectionRect;
    Point mouseDown, mouseHere;

   ...

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        AlphaComposite ta = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.1f);
        g2d.setComposite(ta);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fill(selectionRect);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(selectionRect);
    }
}

public class ExammpleMouseListener extends MouseAdapter    
{    
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {      
        super.mousePressed(e);

        // store the mouse down location
        pnl.mouseDown = e.getPoint();
    }

    /**
     * @see  java.awt.event.MouseAdapter#mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        super.mouseDragged(e);

        // check for left mouse button
        if ((e.getModifiersEx() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // store the current location
        pnl.mouseHere = e.getPoint();

        // calculate the size of the selection rectangle
        double downX = pnl.mouseDown.getX();
        double downY = pnl.mouseDown.getY();
        double hereX = pnl.mouseHere.getX();
        double hereY = pnl.mouseHere.getY();

        double l = Math.min(downX, hereX);
        double t = Math.min(downY, hereY);
        double w = Math.abs(downX - hereX);
        double h = Math.abs(downY - hereY);

        pnl.selectionRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(l, t, w, h);

        // queue a repaint of the panel
        pnl.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        super.mouseReleased(e);

        // clear the selection rectangle
        pnl.selectionRect = null;

        // queue a repaint of the panel
            pnl.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw an interesting way of doing this in JFreeChart's source code. You can draw a marquee over a section of the chart, and when you release the mouse the chart zooms in on the selected are.  Re-rending the chart is expensive and unfortunately JFreeChart doesn't support partial paints of a chart.  So to draw the marquee they do some sort of bitwise operation to the colors of the component, in a reversible fashion.  Every time the mouse moves while selecting a marquee, you reverse the previous bitwise operation on the old coordinates, then redo it on the new coordinates.

Take a look at ChartPanel.java in JFreeChart

```
private void drawZoomRectangle(Graphics2D g2) {
    // Set XOR mode to draw the zoom rectangle
    g2.setXORMode(Color.gray);
    if (this.zoomRectangle != null) {
        if (this.fillZoomRectangle) {
            g2.fill(this.zoomRectangle);
        }
        else {
            g2.draw(this.zoomRectangle);
        }
    }
    // Reset to the default 'overwrite' mode
    g2.setPaintMode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JXLayer](https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/). Span it across the whole form and do the painting in a custom `LayerUI`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here's an simple example with methods for creating and moving the shape.

```
class MyShape implements Shape {

   private Shape shape;

   public void createShape(Point p1, Point p2, ShapeType t) {
      switch(t) {
        case RECTANGLE: {
           shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
           break;
        }
        ... (other shapes)
     }
  }

  public void moveShape(Point lastPoint, Point newPoint, ShapeType t) {
      int xOffset = newPoint.x - lastPoint.x;
      int yOffset = newPoint.y - lastPoint.y;
      switch(t) {
        case RECTANGLE: {
           double x1 = shape.getBounds().getX() + xOffset;
           double y1 = shape.getBounds().getY() + yOffset;
           double w = shape.getBounds().getWidth();
           double h = shape.getBounds().getHeight();
           shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, w, h);
           break;
        }
        ... (other shapes)
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some components ( I don't know if this apply to your components while being dragged )  you can set the background and use a "transparent color"

The Color class does implements Transparency.

To use it you may specify the alpha value in the Color constructor.

For instance this is a semi transparent black background:

```
         // 0: totally transparent 
         // 255: totally opaque, 
         // 192 semy transparent.
         this.setBackground(new Color( 0, 0, 0, 192 ));
```

See the [constructor][1]

Again, I'm not sure if this applies to you. Give it a try

[1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int, int, int, int)